# Appending multiple PDF images vertically to a one page PDF

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I have multiple small tables saved as PDF, and I would like to merge them together vertically into a one page PDF file. There is a lot of white space below each table, so merging them into a one page PDF is not placing them close to each other vertically. I would like to have a small amount of space between each table, and not approximately a full page of space between them. I have tried everything below with a mix of results.

This places everything side by side, and not what I want:

montage fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf final.pdf

This places each fig on a separate page, and not what I want:

gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=final.pdf fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf

This is nicer resolution and puts everything on the same page, but unfortunately keeps the massive white space under the table, which makes for a very long PDF page:

convert -density 150 fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf -append -trim +repage final.pdf

Is there a way I can specify to grab the first so many vertical pixels for each of the figs, and append those to the final PDF? Trim does a great job at removing white space around images, but it appears to only work for the right and left edges of the PDF figures versus all the edges.

Answer (score 2):

Put your -trim +repage right after reading the pdf files and before -append. Add -gravity north so the pages are put to the top center. So try

```
convert -density 150 fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf -trim +repage -gravity north -append final.pdf
```

If you want some space between the pages, you can replace -append with -smush X. Where X is the the amount of space.

```
convert -density 150 fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf -trim +repage -gravity north -smush 20 final.pdf
```

Change the 20 to whatever you want. If you put at 0, then it is the same as -append.

Comment: Unfortunately this command is not working. The output in the final.pdf is all white with no tables. I did manage to get this to work: ```convert -density 150 fig1.pdf fig2.pdf fig3.pdf -crop 1440x900+0+250 -trim -bordercolor White -border 10x10 +repage -append final.pdf``` It's a little hard coded with the crop command, but it works to place all 3 figures on one page with some space between.